Converting timestamps in Perl containing timezone
I need to convert following timestamp containing ms and timezone to yyyy-mm-dd format:
use Time::Piece;
my $created = "2024-07-02T11:20:11.000+0200";
my $test2 = Time::Piece->strptime($created,"%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S.%z")->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");

but I'm getting an error:
Error parsing time at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.18.1/x86_64-linux/Time/Piece.pm line 469.

Would anybody show me a correct way how to do that?

I wish the phrase "timestamp containing timezone" was redundant.

There are several mismatches between your strptime format and your input. You have %Y%m%d at the beginning, which would match 20240702, but your input has 2024-07-02. You have %S.%z at the end, which would match 11.+0200, but your input has 11.000+0200.
To fix the first one, just add dashes to the format.
To fix the second one, well, Time::Piece doesn't understand fractional seconds. If you can guarantee that the string you receive will always be on a full second, you can use a format of %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000%z.
If you can't guarantee that the fraction will always be .000, you can either use a more capable module (DateTime::Format::Strptime would support %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%z), or simply recognize that in the end, the code you've written is equivalent to substr $created, 0, 10.

For date-time strings in arbitrary formats, DateTime::Format::Strptime is often useful.
use feature qw( say );
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );
my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N%z",
   strict   => 1,
   on_error => "croak",
);
my $dt_str = $ARGV[0];
say $format->parse_datetime( $dt_str )->strftime( "%Y-%m-%d" );

$ ./a.pl 2024-07-02T11:20:11.000+0200
2024-07-02


Your input is extremely close to being in a standard format. If your input used +02:00 instead of +0200, it would be consistent with the extremely widely used RFC3339 and ISO8601 standards. You could fix the input then use tools designed to handle those formats.
use feature qw( say );
use DateTime::Format::RFC3339 qw( );
my $dt_str = $ARGV[0];
$dt_str =~ s/[-+]\d\d\K(?=\d\d\z)/:/a;
say DateTime::Format::RFC3339->parse_datetime( $dt_str )->strftime( "%Y-%m-%d" );

$ ./b.pl 2024-07-02T11:20:11.000+0200
2024-07-02

use feature qw( say );
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601 qw( );
my $dt_str = $ARGV[0];
$dt_str =~ s/[-+]\d\d\K(?=\d\d\z)/:/a;
say DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime( $dt_str )->strftime( "%Y-%m-%d" );

$ ./c.pl 2024-07-02T11:20:11.000+0200
2024-07-02


If you don't need validation, the simplest and fastest solution to you problem is to perform a string manipulation.
use feature qw( say );
my $dt_str = $ARGV[0];
$dt_str =~ s/T.*//s;
say $dt_str;

$ ./d.pl 2024-07-02T11:20:11.000+0200
2024-07-02

use feature qw( say );
my $dt_str = $ARGV[0];
substr( $dt_str, 10 ) = "";
say $dt_str;

$ ./e.pl 2024-07-02T11:20:11.000+0200
2024-07-02


I was wondering when someone would show simple string manipulations. Not directed at @ikegami, but the problem in general? Even if you want to validate the timestamp, what would you do if the validation failed? I've seen more then a few problems this week where people wanted to very strict (an Email type!) but don't consider how that just blows up somewhere else when you ignore data that's there because you think you should stop everything because you are locally non-happy.

Initially the issue backs to the library Time::Piece that uses POSIX->strptime , it means based on the documentation here - https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime/ - strftime cannot deal with milliseconds.
1st Solution:
If you need to use the Time::Piece, I suggest to remove milliseconds before converting them.
use Time::Piece;
my $created = "2024-07-02T11:20:11+0200"; # milliseconds removed
my $test2 = Time::Piece->strptime($created,"%FT%T%z")->strftime("%Y-%m-%d"); # %F is equivalent to %Y-%m-%d and %T is equivalent to %H:%M:%S

2nd Solution:
Parse and convert the input to epoch and convert the epoch to desired format
use HTTP::Date;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $current_date = "2024-07-02T11:20:11.00+0200";
my $epoch = str2time($current_date);

my $yyyymmdd = strftime "%Y-%m-%d", localtime($epoch);

